# Upgrade twitter bootstrap using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-rails

Im using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem in my application.

I discovered that this gem uses the  2.3 twitter bootstrap version cause i have to use

```
class="span6"
```

not

```
class="col-md6"
```

when creating a grid.

How can I upgrade to bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails#using-stylesheets-with-less shows you howto include your LESS file, include the LESS files of Twitter's Bootstrap 3 here?

> You have to require Bootstrap LESS (bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)
>   in your application.css
>
> /*  *= require bootstrap_and_overrides  */
>
> /* Your stylesheets goes here... */ To use individual components from
>   bootstrap, your bootstrap_and_overrides.less could look like this: